# NaN still pass boolean condition in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, nan

I want to show value when only it's value is exact number.
So added condition like under. But when values is `NaN`, it still passes condition.
Possible type of value is `number` | `null` | `undefined`.
Following is my code.

```
{value ? <p>{value} people are waiting.</p> : <Skeleton />}
```

I also tried

```
{value && !isNaN(value) ? <p>{value} people are waiting.</p> : <Skeleton />}
```

```
{value && value !== "NaN" ? <p>{value} people are waiting.</p> : <Skeleton />}
```

But result is `NaN people are waiting.` by passing condition.
How can I fix this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: NaN is a non-empty value, so yes it will pass boolean condition. Also, `isNaN(value)` should be `!isNaN(value)`

Comment: Are you sure you haven't got the ternary values swapped around? I don't think you would see your ```<p>``` if value where, say, 3. It would evaluate to true and display ```<Skeleton />``` instead. Also: should ```0``` be displayed as "0 people are waiting" or should it show the skeleton?

Comment: Ah my bad, I edited question again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Number() instead of isNaN it will work fine with your ternary.
But I guess you would want to render `<p>{value} people are waiting.</p>` if your value in not NaN so modify your condition accordingly.

```
 {value && Number(value) ?  <p>{value} people are waiting.</p> :<Skeleton /> }
```

Comment: I think ```value && Number(value)``` might be equivalent to ```Number(value)```?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
{value && !isNaN(value) ? <p>{value} people are waiting.</p> : <Skeleton />}
```

Looks like it was turned around?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to show `Skeleton` when it is not an exact number and your string when it is you could use:

```js
{Number(value) ? <p>{value} people are waiting.</p> : <Skeleton />}
```

This solution should cover most scenarios however; it is possible to end up with:

*"-1 people are waiting."*

To avoid that you could do:

```js
{value > 0 ? <p>{value} people are waiting.</p> : <Skeleton />}
```

When you try to compare against 0, javascript will implicitly try to use value as a number, if that fails, the condition will also fail.

EDIT: I lied! The value `true` will also pass this condition:

```js
['string', //false
 '12', //true
 '0', //false
 'c', //false
 1, //true
 2, //true
 false, //false
 true, //true --> !
 null, //false
 (1/"test"), //false
 -1 //false
].forEach(value => {
    console.log(
        value > 0
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To Check Value is a Number or Not , you can use `isNan()`

```
isNaN(value); //It will return true if not a number else false
```